# How to find changed content types in audit logs

Tags: content-type, auditing

I have auditing enabled and have generated the content type modification log in excel format.

I need to figure out how to find a specific content type that was modified. Any pointers?

Comment: The audit log should have content types by ID, if you don't know the ID for the specific content type you are looking for use powershell to find out: Get-ContentType -Site $site -Name << your content type name>>

Comment: What's the difference between a schema change and a profile change in the audit log?